# Java : unreachable statement for writer.println()?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I got this java code and for some reason the compiler pull an error at `writer.println(linestr);`; Error:(51, 13) java: unreachable statement

```
String linestr ="";
int row = 1, col = 1;
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\User\\Selenium\\scrapjv\\output\\out.txt", "UTF-8");
while(isElementPresent(By.xpath("//div[@id='quotes_content_left_pnlAJAX']/table/tbody/tr[" + row + "]"))) {
    for (col = 1; ; col++) {
        linestr = linestr + driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='quotes_content_left_pnlAJAX']/table/tbody/tr[" + row + "]/td[" + col + "]")).getText() + ",";
    }
    writer.println(linestr);
    row++;
}
writer.close();
```

I just want to convert an html tab into a .csv with `,` separator for columns and `\n` for rows. Do you understand what is bad with my code ? And by the way maybe you know some convenient library to convert an html table into a csv quickly ?

Comment: Comment out the line. The error changed - what is it? Now generalize the error (and the title).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens is that your `for` loop is **infinite**, because you don't specify a *termination condition* nor a `break` statement in the body of the loop:

```
for (col = 1; ; col++)
             ^
```

Therefore, the program will never reach the code after the `for` loop.

Comment: oh wow didn't even notice that i copied the for from another statement that had a break in it... thank's

Answer (score 3):

```
for (col = 1; ; col++) {
```

the above `for` loop has no end condition, so it will never end, thus the statement follows the `for` loop will never be reached.

Here is an example of a `for` loop that ends:

```
for (col = 1; col < 10; col++) {
```